# Holding the div at the fixed x or y positon on scrolling - just testing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-jscrollpane

I am creating a timeline interface using jQuery and CSS. I am using jScrollPane for scrolling it.
I have

- `parent` div which wraps all the div and on which jScrollPane is applied
- `header` div should be fixed while scrolling vertically, but scroll when scrolled horizontally and
- `leftpane` div should be fixed while scrolling horizontally, but scroll when scrolled vertically

Sample Image

[image: Sample image]

JSFiddle Link : http://jsfiddle.net/gACZ8/4/

Any ideas?

Comment: @popnoodles `position:fixed` will cause the div to not scroll at all. for example, i want my `header` div to scroll horizontally, but not vertically.

Comment: Some ambiguity here. What happens to the header when scrolling horizontally and what happens to the leftpane when scrolling vertically? **EDIT**. You just answered that while I was typing.

Comment: Oh... well, there some more relevant info.

Comment: I have edited the question. Hope that brings more clarity!

Comment: ok. jscroll confuses the issue. let's see.

Comment: I am totally not sure how to do this without some javascript help. I'll think on it. So grey and green scroll left and right with red fixed left. Red and grey scroll up and down with green fixed top.  I'll be glad to see the answer to this one.

Comment: use scroll event to determine what you scroll and set positions on-the-fly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [jscrollpane events](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/events.html).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gACZ8/10/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#parent')
    .bind('jsp-scroll-y',
      function(event, scrollPositionY, isAtTop, isAtBottom) {
        $(".header").css("top", scrollPositionY);
      }
    )
    .bind('jsp-scroll-x',
      function(event, scrollPositionX, isAtLeft, isAtRight) {
        $(".lefter").css("left", scrollPositionX);
      }
    )
    .jScrollPane();
});
```

Also you should add `position:relative` to both divs (to move them with top/left without moving other blocks) and `z-index` to header (to make it overflow sidebar).

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/gACZ8/11/

You need to look at the scroll positions of  `.jspPane` which is the div jsScroll creates, and offset the positions of your divs.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#parent').jScrollPane();
  $('#parent').on('scroll', function(){
    var jspPane=$(this).find('.jspPane');
    $('.lefter').css('left', 0-parseFloat(jspPane.css('left')));
    $('.header').css('top', 0-parseFloat(jspPane.css('top')));
  });
});
```

NB your header and leftcol need to be positioned absolutely otherwise they'll push the page contents with them, which means your page has to have margins that avoid these divs, and you need to take care of your z-indexes.

**EDIT**

Or use jscrollpane events (see other answer). I have never used jscrollpane before!

Comment: @popnooldes Thank you very much. Your answer is equally helpful, but I found the other answer more elegant if you are using jScrollPane.

Comment: me too. i have never used it, just figured out what it was doing instead of looking if there were options!